# Is there any formula that maps an int on the range [0..πR²] to the (x,y) coordinates inside the circle of radius R?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, functional-programming, formula

The formula:

```
index(i,w,h) = (i%w, (i/w)%h)
```

uniquely maps each integer `i` on the range `[0..w*h]` to a coordinate inside the rectangle of width `w` and height `h`. Is there any similar formula:

```
index(i,r) = ?
```

that uniquely maps each integer on the range [0..πR²] to a coordinate inside the circle of radius `R`?

Comment: What do you want to do in the (common) case that the number of integer-pairs inside the circle doesn't match the number of integers in `[0, pi r^2]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the most circles with radius R contain less than πR² integer points within the boundary, so usually that map doesn't exist.

Reference: [Gauss circle problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html)

And I suspect that even for good R values there is no simple formula, only iterative aprroach (look at (1) formula in the linked page)